# Can we say that $\sup_{t}\max_Sf(t,S)=\max_S\sup_{t}f(t,S)$ for any bounded function $f$?

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f$ be a function defined over $X\times \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite collection of sets, and $X=\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, Let $f$ be bounded on $X\times \mathcal{C}$. My question is:

> Can we say that $$\sup_{t}\max_S f(t,S)=\max_S\sup_t f(t,S)?$$

I think the answer should be positive as indicated by the following quick analysis that I chalked out:

$$\sup_t\max_Sf(t,S)\ge f(t,S),\ \forall t\in X, Y\in \mathcal{C}\\\implies \sup_t\max_Sf(t,S)\ge \max_S\sup_t f(t,S).$$ Similarly establishing the reverse direction, we find the desired equality.

The above method seems legit to me, but I am not sure if I am missing something, probably some subtle aspect of $\sup$, or something related to compactness of the $X$. I really don't find anything wrong, but it will be really helpful if the experts in this site can kindly verify the validity of the statement, or provide counter-examples, and relevant references for this problem.

BTW, although this seems to me a very standard and classical problem, I could not find anything directly involving the $\sup$ and $\max$, whereas its relative, [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem), which involves $\sup$ and $\inf$ and is true only under certain restrictions on $f$, is a rather famous and useful tool in many parts of analysis.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not find this in the literature because it is quite trivial from definition of supremum.

Comment: Yes, it seemed trivial to me too. But I wanted to make it sure, because I do not have anyone to discuss these things with, and also I am always a little bit cautious when it involves $\sup$. Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always switch the order in which supremum is taken. Of course maximum is same as supremum when it is sup over a finite set. The proof just involves verifying that each side is less than nor equal to the other.

Comment: Okay, so that means my proof is correct, right? There should not be any issue involving compactness of the domain right, as long as the function is bounded?

Comment: Yes, no considerations of continuity compactness etc. It is a special case of the following fact: $sup_i \sup_j a_{ij}=sup_j \sup_i a_{ij}$ for any collection of real numbers $a_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes a rather daunting analysis in my research so much easier.